# docker run fails when importing archive/tar in golang

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to get a golang program that runs on the cmd line to run in a docker container, but importing archive/tar causes errors.

This works:

```
    package main
    import (
            "fmt"
    )
    func main() {
            fmt.Println("success!")
    }
```

producing the output:

```
    liam gotest $ docker run -it gotest
    success!
```

This does not:

```
    package main
    import (
            "archive/tar"
            "fmt"
    )
    var _ = tar.TypeReg
    func main() {
            fmt.Println("success!")
    }
```

producing the output:

```
    liam gotest $ docker run -it gotest
    standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
    FROM scratch
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . /app
    CMD ["./test"]
```

I'm running:

```
go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
ubuntu 18.04LTS
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Solved by vishnu narayanan:

I used

```
`CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo test.go`
```

to build a static executable, and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Why ?***

This is because of the default `go build` behavior. The compiled binary is still looking for libraries in the system path due to dynamic linking.

Since `scratch` is empty, the binary is not able to find the system libraries and throws an error.

***How to solve this ?***

Modify the build script to produce a static compiled build with all libraries built in.

`CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .`

Use the output binary from above build for the docker container.